# How to iterate on select elements with Xpath with one exception?

Tags: xpath

I want to iterate over each selector found that contains a specific class in order to retrieve all elements within the divs. This works until it reaches one item containing an ID.

```
for selector in response.xpath("//div[@class='product-list-entry']"):
```

[image]

My best try to get around this is the following code:

```
for selector in response.xpath("//div[not(@id) and @class='product-list-entry']"):
```

Both versions lead to only retrieving 5 result sets instead of the full list.

How can I simply ignore the one with the id and iterate on all others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should extract the content of the specific divs (examples : text of the div, content of a span and text of a p element) :

```
def parse(self, response):
for selector in response.xpath("//div[@id='product-list']"):
content = selector.xpath(".//div[not(@id)]/text()").extract()
content2= selector.xpath(".//div[not(@id)]/span").extract()
content3= selector.xpath(".//div[not(@id)]/p/text()").extract()
content4= ...
print (content,content2,content3,...)
```